# Stripe: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined at object

Tags: ios, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to add Stripe payments inside of my iOS application with node.js and firebase.

As of now, my main goal is to create a stripe customer when a user creates an account with my application.

I am trying to follow these instructions but I am having issues.

https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/stripe-firebase-swift

```
const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'USD';

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
return stripe.customers.create({
email: user.email,
}).then((customer) => {
return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${user.uid}/customer_id`).set(customer.id);
});
});
```

When I try to run `firebase deploy --only functions` inside of my terminal, I am hit with

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
```

Am I supposed to define token? I assumed it was an autocomplete value associated with stripe?

EDIT to show package.json

```
{
"name": "functions",
"description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"scripts": {
"serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
"shell": "firebase functions:shell",
"start": "npm run shell",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"engines": {
"node": "10"
},
"dependencies": {
"firebase": "^7.15.5",
"firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"

},
"devDependencies": {
"firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`token` in this instance is probably a bit poorly named, what you actually pass into that function is a Stripe API key.

You'll want to first grab your API keys from the [Stripe dashboard directly](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys), then you'll want to set your firebase config to have that API key set:

`firebase functions:config:set stripe.token=<YOUR STRIPE SECRET KEY>`

I've set the parameter to be called `token` so your `index.js` file doesn't need any amendments, however it would be better named as `stripe.secret` or `stripe.apiKey`.

Comment: Fire base functions: would be located inside of my package.Json correct??

Comment: I have edited my questions to show my package.json. would the '"firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"' look like '"firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"' ' config:set stripe.token=<YOUR STRIPE SECRET KEY>?

Comment: Sorry, Im still just confused on where Im supposed to be setting this. Im not very familiar with node.js. could you explain which file you put yours and where inside of that? I tried to create a "token": firebase functions under my logs inside of my package.json, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Hey, friend, I am still having trouble. I have taken your steps but I can't figure out exactly where I should put it

Comment: The command I showed is what you'd run in your terminal to set the `stripe.token` environment variable. You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: That worked! I am running into more issues but I am trying to figure it out thank you.